# Node.js pausing and resuming streams with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, node.js-stream

I'm working with Node.js (v4.4.7) and have written a few lines to play a sound ...

```js
const Speaker = require('audio-speaker/stream');
const Generator = require('audio-generator/stream');

const speaker = new Speaker({
        channels: 1,          // 1 channel 
        bitDepth: 16,         // 16-bit samples 
        sampleRate: 44100     // 44,100 Hz sample rate 
      });

// Streams sample values...
const sound = new Generator(
        //Generator function, returns sample values
        function (time) {
               return Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * time * 2000);
        },
        {
        //Duration of generated stream, in seconds, after which stream will end. 
        duration: Infinity,

        //Periodicity of the time. 
        period: Infinity
       });

// Pipe value stream to speaker
sound.pipe(speaker);
```

...hurray, it works! Now, let's try to pause the sound and resume it after 3 seconds ...

```js
sound.pause();

setTimeout(()=>{
        sound.resume();
        console.log(sound.isPaused());   //  => false
}, 3000);
```

... brilliant, that works as well! And now, let's try the opposite and pause the sound after 3 seconds ...

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
        sound.pause();
        console.log(sound.isPaused()); // => true / although sound is still playing 
}, 3000);
```

... wait, why is this not working? And why does sound.isPaused() shows "true" although sound is still playing. Is it bug or am I doing something wrong?

I went through the Node.js documentation and a couple of tutorials about streams in Node.js and could not find an explanation.In this tutorials they only use setTimout() to resume streams, but they never say anything about why you can not pause a stream this way.

Comment: Share the full source code that doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean? That is the full code.

Comment: Is it a buffer thing?  You wait 3 seconds to pause, maybe it's buffering data during that time, hence the sound continues?  Does it stop eventually?

Comment: I reduced the waiting time to just 10ms, but sound keeps on emitting even after several minutes. I ended up calling the .cork()/uncork method on speaker, that delivers the desired result. But I am still curious why .pause()/.resume() is not working. Is there a way to drain possible buffered data right away, just to make sure sound is empty?

Answer (score 4):

For now, I don't know why calling .pause()/.resume() on the readable stream  is not working as expected. I ended up calling .cork()/.uncork() on the writable stream, that achieves the desired result.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    speaker.cork();
}, 3000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    speaker.uncork();
}, 3000);
```

I will update this answer as soon I have an explanation for this  behaviour.